# Is it possible to create (or simulate) a keyword in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I've just begun learning Ruby, but I've already got big ideas for how I could leverage its uniqueness as an OOPL. My first one is aptly described by the title: is it possible to create (or simulate) a keyword in Ruby? I was playing around a little bit in the repl and discovered some funny things with aliasing.

For example, if you attempt to alias the keyword *class* by saying

```
alias :magic :class
```

It appears to work, because it outputs `nil`. However, it is merely aliasing `Object#class` method; my guess is that there isn't a way to alias a keyword, because keywords are not constants and are likely hard-coded into the interpreter itself.

(This little experiment did have an interesting result, though. Usually, you cannot call the `Object#class` method without an explicit `self` identifier; just typing `class` in the repl yields a syntax error because it gets confused with the keyword `class`. However, by aliasing the `Object#class` method, the interpreter no longer gets confused and so you can use your alias without an identifier. Pretty nifty.)

Right now, with my limited knowledge of Ruby, I believe that a way to simulate a keyword, `class` for example, would be to do something like this:

```
# in some file Magic.rb
module Magic
  def self.type
    # do something to evaluate the given block as a class definition
    yield if block_given?
  end
end

Magic.type Awesome do
  def initialize;end

  def who_am_i?
    puts "I'm Awesome!"
  end
end

x = Awesome.new           # desired output: #<Awesome:0x1234abc>
x.who_am_i?               # desired output: "I'm Awesome!"
```

But that's uglier than what I'd hoped for. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** After some tinkering and Googling, I've discovered what I think to be a nice solution, leveraging anonymous class instantiation, blocks, and `Object#const_set`:

```
def type aName, &block
  Object.const_set(aName, Class.new(Array, &block))
end

type :AwesomeArray do
    def intialize
      puts "Initialized."
    end
    def magic
      puts "DO ALL THE MAGICKS!"
    end
end

x = AwesomeArray.new          # --> #<Awesome:0x12335abc>
puts x.is_a? AwesomeArray     # --> true
puts x.is_a? Array            # --> true
puts x.is_a? Object           # --> true
x.magic                       # --> "DO ALL THE MAGICKS!"
x |= [1, 2, 3]                # --> [1, 2, 3]
```

The user-defined `type` method effectively mimics the `class` keyword. Alternatively, you could call `type` with a string instead of a symbol and adding a `to_sym` call to `aName` when passing it to `Class.new`. Or do both!

```
def type aSymbol, &block
  Object.const_set(aSymbol, Class.new(Array, &block))
end

def type_str aString, &block
  type aString.to_sym, &block
end
```

Now, being a Ruby n00b (r00b?), is there anything inheritantly or conventionally *bad* about doing this? For instance, might it be really expensive or dangerous in some way?

Comment: Is your question about emulating keywords or dynamically creating classes? You can't emulate keywords (they're built-in to parser), but it just so happens that you can create classes in several ways.

Comment: I suppose since I'm only interested in emulating the `class` keyword, my question would be better geared towards the various methods for dynamically creating classes. Do you know of any good resources about the subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR: If you don't have a good reason to do this, DON'T

And by the way, you can't simulate keywords. They're built into the parser. All you can do are metaprogramming hacks like you came up with... but:

---

It's not that it's much more inefficient:

```
       user     system      total        real
type method:   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000034)
class keyword:   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000030)
```

It's just bad form. Why clutter the global namespace with useless methods that make your code harder for anyone else to read? Code is read much more than it is written. Don't make things harder for others or yourself down the road.

This also has some scope gotchas that will come back to byte you later down the road. Example:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > def type aName, &block                                                                                                                                                                                                              
2.0.0p0 :002?>     Object.const_set(aName, Class.new(Array, &block))                                                                                                                                                                               
2.0.0p0 :003?>   end                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 => nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2.0.0p0 :004 > a = 'hi'
 => "hi" 
2.0.0p0 :005 > type :Hi1 do
2.0.0p0 :006 >     puts a
2.0.0p0 :007?>   end
hi
 => Hi1 
2.0.0p0 :008 > class Hi2
2.0.0p0 :009?>   puts a
2.0.0p0 :010?> end 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for Hi2:Class
        from (irb):9:in `<class:Hi2>'
        from (irb):8
```

Block scope is different than `class` scope. Also, this doesn't handle class variables right (although you should never use Ruby's class variables without very good reason...):

```
2.0.0p0 :012 > type :T1 do
2.0.0p0 :013 >     @@t1test = 'hi'
2.0.0p0 :014?>   end
(irb):13: warning: class variable access from toplevel
 => T1 
2.0.0p0 :015 > T1.class_variables
 => [:@@t1test]  
2.0.0p0 :018 > class T2
2.0.0p0 :019?>   @@t2test = 'bork'
2.0.0p0 :020?>   end
 => "bork" 
2.0.0p0 :021 > Object.class_variables
 => [:@@t1test] 
2.0.0p0 :022 > T2.class_variables
 => [:@@t2test, :@@t1test]
```

As you can see, your block form leaks the class variable to *every single class* (that is descended from Object). Not exactly good.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I really didn't plan on using this, it was just an idea that I had when I was working on a project. I found myself writing a lot of classes that would all extend the same parent, and I got to thinking about how it might be possible to change the default/implicit inheritance from Object to something else. Then I saw how you can specify the parent with the `Class#new` method and thought it might come in handy as a sort of macro (I haven't looked at how to implement macros in Ruby yet). Seeing the scope issues, though, I've abandoned this route.

Comment: @DesAdams: Ruby has no macros. Sorry. By the way, take a look at the C code for BASH (or was it SH) to see why things like this are a bad idea. They wrote a macro for almost every single C keyword, to make it look more like shell code. It's not pretty.

Comment: Overriding and aliasing are wonderful tools until the language stops acting like it's supposed to. It used to make me nuts seeing operators used in wild and wacky ways back in the wild-wild-west of early C++.

Comment: tbh, I'd love the ability to alias "else" as "otherwise"...

Answer (score 1):

Of course `alias` comes with a cost if you use it without good reason. A language is a language because there are many people using it.

If you break the convention it becomes your own language.

Comment: While I've thought many times that it would be cool/fun to write my own language, that was not my intention here lol.